# Adding BigDecimals with user input

Tags: java

I'm having problem to add two objects (BigDecimals) which supposed to be taken from the user, i.e. user inputs two bigdecimals, on the output program should show the exact result with all decimals considered.

Sample of I/O
Input:
**3.14** 
**3.143111**
Output: **6.283111**

I'm trying to use objects called BigDecimals, but I can't use typical scanner function since the object BigDecimal has to be 'initiated' by some value, and I would like to leave it empty so that user will be able to type in the exact floating point. 
I would like to use BigDecimal instead of float type since it's more accurate. 
Here is just an example how to add two BigDecimals types but I can't figure out how to input the value of above mentioned objects.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class home {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  BigDecimal bg1,bg2,bg3;

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 


  bg1 = new BigDecimal(3.14);
  bg2 = new BigDecimal(3.143111);



  MathContext mc = new MathContext(7);


  bg3=bg1.add(bg2,mc);


  System.out.println("Result is " + bg3);
 } 
}
```

**How can I possibly determine the value of MathContext by user ? 
Should I just add some int variable in brackets() while creating new object MathContext which will be determined by user ?**

Comment: Why do you need a MathContext? You can add two BigDecimals without it.

Comment: Have you tried with `scan.nextBigDecimal();` for user input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it for you

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class home {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
  BigDecimal bg1 = scan.nextBigDecimal();
  BigDecimal bg2 = scan.nextBigDecimal();

  System.out.println("Result is " + bg1.add(bg2));
 } 
}
```

Comment: did try similar thing but I was missing BigDecimal library, great stuff. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(<string read in from command line>)
```